# How to add OAuth 2.0 authentication with smtp to send email using javascript?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail

I need to add oauth 2.0 security in my existing email submission form. There are some other methods that I found online but as I am using smtp, I just want to add the necessary code and tokens. But don't know how to code it right.

JAVASCRIPT

```
        function sendmail()

        {

        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();

        // var body = $('#body').val();

        var Body='name: '+name+'<br>email: '+email+'<br>subject: '+subject+'<br>message: '+message;
        //console.log(name, phone, email, message);

        Email.send({
            SecureToken : "",
            To : '',
            From : '',
            Subject: "New message on contact from "+name,
            Body: Body
        }).then(
            message =>{
                //console.log (message);
                if(message=='OK'){
                alert('E-mail has been sent successfully. Thank you ...');
                }
                else{
                    console.error (message);
                    alert('Error at sending message ...')
                    
                }

            }
        );

    }
```

Currently only this much javascript code is sending email using smtp protocol. But gmail is disabling access for less secure app. So what do I need to add to include oauth 2.0?

Comment: which oauth role(s) are you trying to set up?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to send the email from the client instead of a backend/server? Am I right?

** Oh nevermind I see. It sends the token to smtp.js and then they make the smtp connection to gmail?

Comment: It's a contact page for website. If anyone wants to send a message, the html form data will be submitted into my email.

Comment: You are right. There is probably client, smtp server and gmail service involved. How can I add the OAuth 2.0 authentication ...?

Comment: What role of oAuth2 are you trying to implement?

Comment: I don't know what role of OAuth2 is it ...? But you understand the process. Probably you know what is the role ...

Comment: 1. I would highly recommend you **never** put your email in a public space, only if it is a spam/trash one.

2. [Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) will be disabled soon, you have roughly one month left, so probably this is why it's not working.

3. You will probably need to change this current outdated system

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, im not seeing anything related to [Oauth](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) in your code currently.

Comment: I don't know about the code for oauth 2.0 authorization and didn't find any code related to this smtp approach. I was hoping if someone knows the code and help me out here then I will try ...